# Prove $(((p\land q)\to r)\land(p \to q))\to (p \to r)$ is satisfiable.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I'm trying to learn how to apply shortcuts of a truth table, and was wondering if the following is correct:

Let $A=(p\land q)$

Let $B = (A \to r)$

Let $C=(p \to q)$

Let $D=(B\land C)$

Let $E=(p \to r)$

Let $F=(D\to E)$

Proof by contradiction, assume equation is not satisfiable, 
therefore $v(F)=f=v((D\to E))=F_{\to} (v(D),v(E))$, which means $v(D)=t$, and $v(E)=f$, by Definition Value of a Formula in a State $v$.

1. $v(E)=f=F_{\to} (v(p),v(r)), v(r)=f$ and $v(p)=t$, by Definition
2. $v(D)=t=v(B\land C)=F_{\land} (v(B),v(C)), v(B)=t$, and $v(C)=t$ by Definition.
3. $v(B)=t=F_{\to} (v(A),v(r)), v(A)=f$, since $v(r)=f$ in Step 1.
4. $v(C)=t=F_{\to} (v(p),v(q)),v(q)=t$, since $v(p)=t$ in Step 1.
5. $v(A)=f=F_{\land} (v(p),v(q))$ – not possible as $v(p),v(q)=t$ from (1), and (4) respectively.

Therefore The above equation is satisfiable by shortcut method. QED.

Comment: I didn't read your proof, it could be correct, but even if it is, it's not the right way to think about this, in my opinion. To prove that the formula is satisfiable, you need to find a combination of truth values for the propositional letters $p, q,$ and $r$ such that the formula evaluates to true. With this in mind, and given that the formula is a conditional statement, it's enough to try to make the antecedent false. And the antecedent is a conjunction of formulas, one of which is very simple ($p\to q$).

Comment: Perhaps you wanted to write $C=(p\to q)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you proved by contradiction that the negation of $F$ is not satisfiable. It follows that $F$ is a tautology, and hence satisfiable.

Answer (score 1):

This statement is a tautology (natural deduction style like proof):

assume the left hand side

$((p\land q)\to r)\land(p \to q))$ holds
and assume $p$. Then $p \to q$ tells us $q$ holds, so
$p \land q$ holds.

So by $(p \land q) \to r$ we conclude $r$ and we have shown $p \to r$ and hence
the total statement.

So any choice of truth values will make it true.